# Convert timeseries frequency from hourly to 15-mins

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have 2 Time-series dataframes
df1 : one hour interval basis
df2 : 15 mins interval basis

How Can i convert ONE HOUR(df1) into 15mins interval dataframe so that i can get both the timeseries at same scale?

Example:
df1

[image]

df2
[image]

**How can i convert one row of df1 into 4 rows with 15mins of interval (shown in df2) in pandas?**

Answer (score 0):

If there is multiple columns and need downsample DataFrame by column `Date` with aggregate function `mean` use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df1 = df1.resample('15Min', on='Date').mean()
```

If there is `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df1 = df1.resample('15Min').mean()
```